# Show that $y^2 \frac{d^2y}{dx^2}+1=0$ for a set of parametric equations.

Tags: calculus, parametric

A function of $x$ is defined parametrically by $x=t-\sin(t)$ and $y=1-\cos(t).$

How do I answer this question, then?

Show that $$y^2 \dfrac{d^2y}{dx^2}+1=0.$$

Comment: May be, you could start with $$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{\frac{dy}{dt}}{\frac{dx}{dt}}$$

Comment: is this not the cycloid?

Comment: What's the step after that?

Answer (score 1):

$dx = dt - \cos t dt, dy = \sin t dt$ so $\dfrac{dy}{dx} = \dfrac{\sin t}{  1 - \cos t}$.

now  use the fact
$$\dfrac{d^2y}{dx^2} = {\dfrac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right) \over \frac{dx}{dt}}$$